# Kentico form - Display/populate item ID

Tags: kentico

I have a Kentico form (bizform) and am able to display all the user's submissions using transformation like below. What I'm unable to display is the item ID value (line 2 in the code below). The field is Kentico-generated field / primary key. What I got is just the text "True" instead of the integer value of the field. It looks so simple, but looks like I missed something very basic. Thanks for help!

```
<td>{% FirstName %} {% LastName %} </td>

<td>{% demo_requestID %}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like `{% ToInt(demo_requestID) %}`

Comment: Hi Brenden, I did that and got the value = 0 for all records (instead of 1, 2, 3...)

Comment: It's an error on my part. I missed adding the demo_requestID to the custom query statement!

Comment: Not having that in your custom query may have been the underlying issue vs. converting it `ToInt()`